# using due to at the end of a sentence

Tags: phrase-usage

Consider the following sentence from this [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/269823/6341):

> Had there not been modern communication platforms across the globe,
> scientific progress would have been impossible.

Now I want to give more explanation to the cause and effect. I wonder if it is correct to add **"due to ..."** at the end of the sentence? I have to explain how lack of modern communication affects scientific progress.

> Had there not been modern communication platforms across the globe,
> scientific progress would have been impossible ***due to lack of
> contribution.***

Is it a good modification? Does it clarify the relation between the two or it just makes the sentence more complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Had there not been modern communication platforms across the globe scientific progress would have been impossible*" is long and a bit clunky!

This is shorter:

*Without modern, global communication platforms, scientific progress would have been impossible.*

If you were happy with that, the sentence could continue with **as...** or **because...**
 I don't know what 'contribution' means here, but perhaps you could say:
*...because no-one would have contributed*
or
 *...as there were insufficient contributions* (or *no contributions*).

"Due to" is happiest accompanying the verb *to be*:

> *his illness **was due** to smoking*
>   not:
>  *he became ill due to smoking*.

But it is used more freely nowadays and my misgivings may **be due** to my age.

"*lack of contribution*" needs either '**the**' or '**a**' before it. And it should be plural:

- **the/a** lack of contribution**s**.

'a shortage' might be better than 'a lack'. If there were none at all 'an absence' might be better.

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider the use of the expression

> ***for lack of***

[MWebster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for%20lack%20of#:%7E:text=%3A%20not%20having%20(the%20thing%20specified,we%20went%20to%20the%20park)) defines it as

```
not having (the thing specified)
```

So your sentence would look like this

> Had there not been modern communication platforms across the globe, scientific progress would have been impossible ***for lack of contributions.***

I agree that ***contributions*** needs to be in the plural.

Answer (score 1):

It's grammatically fine, but stylistically I don't think it's a good modification. It makes an already long sentence longer, and doesn't add a lot of clarity. If you feel the connection between the two concepts needs additional support, consider a new sentence.

I would also suggest that it may not be necessary at all, depending on your audience. I expect most people are comfortable with the connection between communication and scientific process.